# Getting OpenSea collections by name

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, nft, opensea

Is there any API or SDK which do following thing:
It returns the chain type like Ethereum, Solana, etc of provided collection. Input would be collection name or collection slug based on OpenSea.

Any workaround or multiple api calls beyond OpenSea are also ok.

Example :

Input -> boredapeyachtclub

Output -> Ethereum

Answer (score 0):

This [OpenSea API](https://docs.opensea.io/reference/api-overview) may be help you :)

Comment: I checked all the APIs. I didn't find what I was looking for according to my question. Can you point out which API are you referring exactly?